# How to find the largest intersection among multiple subsets (most common element in n out of k sets)?

Tags: python-3.x, set, combinations, intersection

Just an example:

```
set_0={0,3,4}
set_1={1,3,4}
set_2={1,5,23,8,24}
set_4={1,2,6,10}
set_5={1,60,34,2}
set_6={1,45,32,4}
set_7={1,6,9,14}
set_8={1,56,3,23}
set_9={1,34,23,3}
all_intersection=set.intersection(set_0,set_1,set_2,set_3,set_4, set_5, set_6, set_7, set_8, set_9)
```

gives empty set. Is there any way I can find the intersection among all possible combinations of 9 out of 10 sets in a pythonic way (perhaps without the brute force approach).

For this dataset I would expect to retrieve 1.

Comment: give an examples of your sets

Comment: I just edited it, adding an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to call intersection on the class `set` is going to lead to errors, because the returned methods are descriptors.

Though, looks like you need to choose a set from which to form a basis of intersection. But, that intersection won't find the most common value, it will tell you which value is in each set at least once. The `Counter` class from collections can tell you which values are the most common.

```
from collections import Counter

set_0 = {0, 3, 4}
set_1 = {1, 3, 4}
set_2 = {1, 5, 23, 8, 24}
set_4 = {1, 2, 6, 10}  # you're missing set_3
set_5 = {1, 60, 34, 2}
set_6 = {1, 45, 32, 4}
set_7 = {1, 6, 9, 14}
set_8 = {1, 56, 3, 23}
set_9 = {1, 34, 23, 3}

my_sets = (set_0, set_1, set_2, set_4, set_5, set_6, set_7, set_8, set_9)
values_of_interest = set().union(*my_sets)

values_shared_among_all_sets = values_of_interest.intersection(*my_sets)
counter = Counter(item for collection in my_sets for item in collection)
the_5_most_common_values = counter.most_common(5)

print(f"values in all sets: {values_shared_among_all_sets}")
print(f"most common 5 values: {the_5_most_common_values}")

# this is the output
values in all sets: set()
most common 5 values: [(1, 8), (3, 4), (4, 3), (23, 3), (2, 2)]
```